# robospice doesn't cache relations of POJO classes

Tags: android, spring, jackson, robospice

I'm working on an android application using robospice, spring and jackson. Everything works fine except that cache results don't have relations of POJO classes.

For instance;

```
public class User extends SampleBase {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Address address;
}

public class Address extends SampleBase {
    public int id;
    public String street;
    public String city;
}

public class SampleBase {
    // Base class of all POJO classes
}
```

When I send a request to get a user, I get all the values properly. However, when I try to get a user from cache, the address field returns null. If there's a relation between two classes, those relation fields are null but other fields are OK.

The result of request:

```
User:
    id:       1
    name:     "Test User"
    address:  Address Object
```

The result of cache:

```
User:
    id:       1
    name:     "Test User"
    address:  null
```

In my design, all of the POJO classes extend SampleBase. And there is only one RequestListener:

```
public class SampleRequestListener implements RequestListener<SampleBase> {

     @Override
     public void onRequestSuccess(SampleBase result) {
         // Some operations
     }

     @Override
     public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException e) {
         // Some operations
     }
}
```

I don't know if it's about my request listener but this works fine while sending requests. Is there something else that I should do to get the related objects of a cached object?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, we often do this and it works fine. Try to find some solution on jackson forum, RS is just a wrapper here.